# Firefox SDK: simpre-prefs: is it possible to change the label of the control-button?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing code that capture hotkey after user press `control`-button in preferences of addon - I want to change the `label` when user push the button and change again when user push some keys (to display the new hotkey). [Official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) about `simple-prefs` not mention that I can change something visual in loaded preferences view and in debug I looked into object `prefs` and saw that my preferences is just a strings - only the values and types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can unless you hack the preferences page. I saw your other question and the example add-on from the answer. It's not using simple-prefs and I don't think it's a great user experience either. I have the same problem and was thinking to use a control button to bring up a panel on which you can listen to the keystrokes and print them there. A panel is all html so you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks man for posting. I didn't udnerstand what he was doing so was trying to help him somehow. I also prefer xhtml pages for example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ (the xhtml gives it the localization capabilities)

Comment: No problem. Not sure how future proof xhtml is for preferences though. I though `about:` pages are going away at some point? I like simple-prefs because of the consistent user experience and because I don't like to reinvent wheels, but not having anything for keyboard shortcuts is a big gap. From what I read, better keyboard shortcut support is on Firefox' roadmap. Let's see what will come...